# How to disable GNOME's 8 sec. shift hotkey for activating slow keys/keystroke delay?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell, accessibility

When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> for 8 seconds (as the upcoming dialog says, I rather feel these are 10 seconds) GNOME enables "slow keys", [how they call it](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/a11y-slowkeys.html.en).

Fortunately a dialog pops up before it is finally enabled. However that cannot be quickly dismissed by navigation with the keyboard (you can only *click* on "Cancel", moving with the keyboard's arrow keys does not work) or by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>. I found out, however, that you can close it by holding <kbd>ESC</kbd> for several seconds, too.
(I would add a screenshot of that prompt here, but unfortunately this is not possible to screenshot it.)

My **use case** is just gaming on Linux or stuff like this, where it is perfectly fine when you hold the shift key for a longer time. As such, I do not want this dialog to pop up and dismissing it in the middle of a game is also *very* annoying.

As such my question is: **How can I disable this prompt for enabling the keystroke delay?**

---

The help file already linked above [does state there is a setting for it](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/a11y-slowkeys.html.en):

> Under *Enable by Keyboard*, select *Turn on accessibility features* from the keyboard to turn slow keys on and off from the keyboard. When this option is selected, you can press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> for eight seconds to enable or disable slow keys.

However, the mentioned setting *is already disabled* in my case:
[image: Setting "Enable by keyboard" with description "Turn accessibility features on and off using the keyboard" is shown in disabled state with a slider in "Off" position. Title of the window: "Typing Assist"]

GNOME 3.28.2, Fedora 28

---

This question has been [cross-posted on ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/128015/how-to-disable-gnomes-8-sec-shift-hotkey-for-activating-slow-keyskeystroke-delay/).

Comment: What's the output of `dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/keyboard/enable` ?

Comment: @don_crissti It's "false".

Comment: That's how it should be, so it does not look like a configuration problem to me. I can't replicate that behavior on arch linux (pressing SHIFT even for more than 10 secs has no effect).

Comment: Okay, reported [this as a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/697).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question as answered: In the question you can see how to do it, it is actually possible in the visible settings application.

There [only was a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/358) that prevented this from working correctly in GNOME 3.28 at least, and [has been fixed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/merge_requests/501) (to be released in v3.32, I guess.).